# ¿Como puedo enviar el mismo formulario pero con distintos valores y PHPs distintos, después de validarlos?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

estoy intentando enviar 2 formularios que se encuentran en una modal, lo tengo tal que así en el footer:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                    <input type="hidden" id="idObra" name="idobra" value="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success editar" id="editar" style="display:none;">Guardar cambios</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success alta" id="alta">Dar de Alta</button>

                </div>
```

El caso es que quiero que cuando le de al botón de dar alta, pueda dar de alta, pero cuando hago click en editar, se abra la misma modal. Estoy utilizando el plugin validate de jquery, lo que necesito hacer es distinguir de algún modo la acción que estoy pulsando.

**Código del Alta:**

```
$(".form").validate({
    rules: {
        nombre: {
            required: true
        },
        fechainicio:{
            required:true
        },
        contratista:{
            required:true
        },

        direccion:{
            required:true,
        },

        poblacion:{
            required:true,
        },
        presupuesto:{
            required:true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        nombre: {
            required: "No dejes el nombre en blanco."
        },

        fechainicio:{
            required: "No dejas la fecha de inicio vacía."
        },


        contratista:{
            required: "Debes seleccionar un contratista."
        },

        direccion:{
            required: "No dejes la dirección en blanco."
        },

        poblacion:{
            required: "No dejes la población en blanco."
        },

        presupuesto:
        {
            required: "Debes introducir el presupuesto Inicial de la Obra."
        }
       
    },
    errorClass: "help-inline text-danger",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
    },
   
    submitHandler: function(form,e) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Fomulario Enviado');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'funciones/obras/fun_alta_obra.php',
            dataType: "html",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(res) {
                $("#actuObra").load(" #actuObra",function(res,status,xhr)
                {
                    if (status=="success")
                    {
                        makeTable();
                        $("#nueva_obra").modal('hide');
                    }
                });
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert("No se puede conectar con el servidor, ha ocurrido un error");

            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Código del Editar:**

```
 $(".form").validate({
    rules: {
        nombre: {
            required: true
        },
        fechainicio:{
            required:true
        },
        contratista:{
            required:true
        },

        direccion:{
            required:true,
        },

        poblacion:{
            required:true,
        },
        presupuesto:{
            required:true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        nombre: {
            required: "No dejes el nombre en blanco."
        },

        fechainicio:{
            required: "No dejas la fecha de inicio vacía."
        },


        contratista:{
            required: "Debes seleccionar un contratista."
        },

        direccion:{
            required: "No dejes la dirección en blanco."
        },

        poblacion:{
            required: "No dejes la población en blanco."
        },

        presupuesto:
        {
            required: "Debes introducir el presupuesto Inicial de la Obra."
        }
       
    },
    errorClass: "help-inline text-danger",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
    },
   
    submitHandler: function(form,e) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Fomulario Enviado');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'funciones/obras/fun_edit_obra.php',
            dataType: "html",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(res) {
                $("#actuObra").load(" #actuObra",function(res,status,xhr)
                {
                    if (status=="success")
                    {
                        makeTable();
                        $("#nueva_obra").modal('hide');
                    }
                });
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert("No se puede conectar con el servidor, ha ocurrido un error");

            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Haga lo que haga, siempre entra en el alta, he probado tambíen a distinguirlo con la funcion click para realizar cada una de las acciones, pero no da ningun resultado, es la primera vez que uso el plugin de validate, y no se si es exactamente así como se debe hacer,

Comment: Por que no pones a cada botón un evento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

le he encontrado una solución que es posible que no sea la más efectiva, pero funciona perfecto y sirve

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                <input type="hidden" id="idObra" name="idobra" value="">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editar" style="display:none;" onclick="editar();">Guardar cambios</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success alta" >Dar de Alta</button>

            </div>
```

Asigne un botón al editar y le puse un evento onclick.

Como ya había validado el form anteriormente, hice lo siguiente:

```
function editar(){
$(".form").validate();
if ($('.form').valid())
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"funciones/obras/fun_edit_obra.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(res) {
          $("#actuObra").load(" #actuObra", function(res, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "success") {
              makeTable();
              $("#nueva_obra").modal('hide');
            }
          });
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("No se puede conectar con el servidor, ha ocurrido un error");
    
        }
      });
}
```

Y con esto ya estaría. Por si alguien le puede servir en un futuro.

Answer (score 1):

Estuve mirando tus dos codigos y lo único que cambia es esta linea de aquí:

```
url: 'funciones/obras/fun_edit_obra.php',
```

Es decir, el endpoint.

Ahora bien, vi que tenias ya dentro de tu `form` dos inputs con un `id` diferente:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success editar" id="editar" style="display:none;">Guardar cambios</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success alta" id="alta">Dar de Alta</button>
```

Para realizar algo interesante con estos `inputs` puedes leer este post relacionado de aqui:

[difference-between-this-and-event-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077859/difference-between-this-and-event-target)

En el que se explica la diferencia entre `this` y `event.target`, a nosotros lo que nos interesa entonces es usar `event.target` segun esa definición.

Entonces podemos aprovecharnos de ambos `ID` dentro de tu `submitHandler` para poder enviar la petición al endpoint correcto.

En la parte de aquí harías lo siguiente:

```
submitHandler: function(form, e) {

  const clickID = e.target.id;
  const url = 
    clickID === "alta" ? 
      "funciones/obras/fun_alta_obra.php" : "funciones/obras/fun_edit_obra.php";

  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Fomulario Enviado');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url,
    dataType: "html",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(res) {
      $("#actuObra").load(" #actuObra", function(res, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
          makeTable();
          $("#nueva_obra").modal('hide');
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("No se puede conectar con el servidor, ha ocurrido un error");

    }
  });
  return false;

}
```

Como vemos nos aprovechamos del `ID` para marcar una diferencia y llegar al endpoint correcto:

```
const clickID = e.target.id;
  const url = 
    clickID === "alta" ? 
      "funciones/obras/fun_alta_obra.php" : "funciones/obras/fun_edit_obra.php";


...
...
...
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url,
```

Ahh por cierto esto de aqui es incorrecto y debes revisarlo:

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

Es incorrecto porque si tienes mas de un `form` estas apuntando ya sea a ambos o a cualquiera, debes de utilizar mas bien el `this`, que te permitira hacer referencia al elemento actual:

```
$(this).serialize()
```

Comment: Buenas ante todo, gracias por tu respuesta, estuve probando ese código, pero creo que no me he llegado a explicar del todo bien, el caso es que el formulario es el mismo, hasta ahora lo estaba haciendo mendiante el evento onclick y asignando una función que me enviara el form, pero al querer usar el validate, ha cambiado mi metodología, el caso es que nunca he puesto dos ids diferentes, simplemente al mismo formulario, dependiendo de al botón en el que haga click, llame a una url u otra. Creo recordar que también tengo un problema con el código y es que tengo un fallo de this.settings=null.

Comment: No habia revisado que tenias dos input de tipo submit, en ese caso dejame modifico la respuesta, ya que estoy viendo que puede modificarse de acuerdo a esos dos botones

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta, porfavor mira detenidamente que cosas han cambiado.

Comment: Buenas de nueva, me ayudó en parte tu pregunta, pero aún no funciona del todo, cuando pongo el $(this) me sale el settings null, ahora bien, no entiendo muy bien esta linea: `const url = 
    clickID === "alta" ? 
      "funciones/obras/fun_alta_obra.php" : "funciones/obras/fun_edit_obra.php";` Ahora siempre me hace el editar, todavía no le encuentro solución al problema.

Comment: Recuerda que `this` hace referencia a en ese caso tu formulario, no tiene sentido que `this.settings` sea cualquier cosa diferente de `null`, ya que se supone que un formulario no tiene ningun atributo llamado `settings`, para el segundo caso...  si tienes un solo formulario deberia estar funcionando... hare una prueba mas a ver que puede ser, por el momento mientras edito de nuevo la respuesta quedate con que eso que ves ahi es una asignacion condicional corta, o tambien llamada `shorthand if` que te permite asignar valores de acuerdo a una condicion.

Comment: Buenas, indagando en el problema, he descubierto que pulse al botón que le pulse,el valor de la url siempre es la de editar.Nunca entra en la url del alta, a pesar de hacer click en el botón